# issue with simplexml_load_string parsing

Tags: php, xml, parsing

i'm trying to pass some xml data into a PHP variable , then to use within javascript charts

my string variable is as follow:

```
$temp = '<chart manageResize="1" dateFormat="dd/mm/yyyy" ganttLineColor="CCCCCC" ganttLineAlpha="20" gridBorderAlpha="20" showTaskNames="1" hoverCapBgColor="F1F1F1" hoverCapBorderColor="333333" paletteThemeColor="333333" hoverBandColor="3d3d3d" hoverBandAlpha="95" showGanttPaneHorizontalHoverBand="0" showGanttPaneVerticalHoverBand="0">\n\
<categories bgColor="333333"  baseFont="Arial" baseFontCOlor="FFFFFF" baseFontSize="12" showhoverband="0" >\n\
    <category start="1/1/2005" end="31/5/2005" align="center" name="Sales Territory Assignment" fontColor="ffffff" isBold="1" fontSize="16" />\n\
</categories>\n\
<categories font="Arial" fontColor="ffffff" isBold="1" fontSize="12" bgColor="333333">\n\
    <category start="1/1/2005" end="31/1/2005" name="January" />\n\
    <category start="1/2/2005" end="28/2/2005" name="February" />\n\
    <category start="1/3/2005" end="31/3/2005" name="March" />\n\
    <category start="1/4/2005" end="30/4/2005" name="April"/>\n\
    <category start="1/5/2005" end="31/5/2005" name="May" />\n\
</categories>\n\
<processes headerbgColor="333333" fontColor="ffffff" fontSize="12" bgColor="333333" align="right" >\n\
    <process Name="Tom" id="1" />\n\
    <process Name="Harry" id="2" />\n\
    <process Name="Mary" id="4" />\n\
    <process Name="Mike" id="3" />\n\
</processes>\n\
<tasks  color="" alpha="" font="" fontColor="" fontSize="" isAnimated="1">\n\
    <task name="North" processId="1" start="3/1/2005" end="4/2/2005" Id="1_1" color="e1f5ff" borderColor="AFD8F8"/>\n\
    <task name="East" processId="1" start="6/2/2005" end="24/3/2005" Id="1_2" color="e1f5ff" borderColor="AFD8F8"/>\n\
    <task name="Vacation" processId="1" start="25/3/2005" end="18/4/2005" Id="1_3" color="e1f5ff" borderColor="AFD8F8" height="2" showBorder="1" topPadding="49%"/>\n\
    <task name="South" processId="1" start="18/4/2005" end="24/5/2005" Id="1_4" color="e1f5ff" borderColor="AFD8F8"/>\n\
    <task name="South" processId="2" start="15/1/2005" end="5/3/2005" Id="2_1" color="F6BD0F" borderColor="F6BD0F"/>\n\
    <task name="West" processId="2" start="21/3/2005" end="10/5/2005" Id="2_2" color="F6BD0F" borderColor="F6BD0F"/>\n\
    <task name="Global" processId="3" start="7/1/2005" end="26/5/2005" Id="3_1" width="12" color="8BBA00" borderColor="8BBA00"/>\n\
    <task name="South" processId="4" start="13/3/2005" end="19/4/2005" Id="4_1" width="12" color="FF654F" borderColor="FF654F" />\n\
</tasks>\n\
\n\
</chart>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($temp, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);//LIBXML_NOCDATA LIBXML_NOWARNING 

// see object structure 
print_r($xml);
```

now, i want this hole string to be passed into my chart , but the print statement show this output:

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [manageResize] => 1
>   [dateFormat] => dd/mm/yyyy [ganttLineColor] => CCCCCC [ganttLineAlpha]
>   => 20 [gridBorderAlpha] => 20 [showTaskNames] => 1 [hoverCapBgColor] => F1F1F1 [hoverCapBorderColor] => 333333 [paletteThemeColor] => 333333 [hoverBandColor] => 3d3d3d [hoverBandAlpha] => 95
>   [showGanttPaneHorizontalHoverBand] => 0
>   [showGanttPaneVerticalHoverBand] => 0 ) [categories] => Array ( [0] =>
>   \n\ \n\ [1] => \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ ) [processes] => \n\ \n\ \n\
>   \n\ \n\ [tasks] => \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ )

many lines discarded and just (\n) appears instead of them , i tried to free my xml of the (\n)

i've tried to use huge data parse (LIBXML_PARSEHUGE) but does not affect anything
any idea please?

Comment: You may want to use this function libxml_disable_entity_loader(true); before you call the function simplexml_load_string() to protect your XML parser against this https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_%28XXE%29_Processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to debug / dump your `SimpleXMLElement` you can't just `print_r` it.

Use [`asXML()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) instead:

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Note that if you want to see this output in your browser, you'll need to wrap it with `htmlentities()`. And if you want the output to include line breaks use `nl2br()`.

```
echo nl2br(htmlentities($xml->asXML()));
```

Comment: result is:
\n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\ \n\

Comment: @Anas View source. =) It's all there, your browser just isn't showing it. That, or stick a "<pre>" tag at the top.

Comment: no , the parser does not output all the string within the variable for example:
    [processes] => \n\

Comment: @Anas When I use your code, and then `echo nl2br(htmlentities($xml->asXML()))` I get all the same XML, nothing is missing.

Comment: @Anas `[processes] => ` is `print_r` output